# Display Json array data in jqGrid

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I'm developing web based project with Spring MVC, hibernate & jquery with jetty server..
i want to display data regarding to json response.
here is my Json method in Controller Class.(i need show Harbors' details in my grid)

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name="HARBOUR")
public class Harbour {

```
@Id
@Column(name="HARBOUR_ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer harbourId;

@Column(name="HARBOURCODE")
private String harbourCode;

@Column(name="HARBOURNAME")
private String harbourName;

@Column(name="STREETNO")
private String streetNo;

@Column(name="STREETONE")
private String streetOne;

@Column(name="STREETTWO")
private String streetTwo;

@Column(name="CITYNAME")
private String cityName;

@Column(name="PROVINCE")
private String province;

@Column(name="ALL_ID")
private String allocationId; & Getter & Setters
```

& this is my Controller Class Method that is used to generate json array as response

```
@RequestMapping("/selectHarbour")
public ModelAndView selectHarbour(Map<String, Object> map,HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {

    List <Harbour> list= harbourService.listHarbour();
    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
    for(Harbour harbour:list){
        JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
        array.put(harbour.getHarbourId());
        array.put(harbour.getHarbourCode());
        array.put(harbour.getHarbourName());
        array.put(harbour.getCityName());
        array.put(harbour.getProvince());
        jsonArray.put(array);
    }
    response.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());
    return null;
    }catch(Exception exception){
        System.out.println("error is "+exception);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And finally this is my Jquery for generate jqGrid.

```
<td colspan="2">
        <!-- Insert Data Tables -->
        <table id="list5"></table> 
        <div id="pager5"></div> 
        <br /> 
        <a href="#" id="a1">Get data from selected row</a> 
        <br /> 
    </td>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#list5").jqGrid({ 
    url:'selectHarbour.html', 
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'], 
            colModel:[ 
                       {name:'id',index:'id', width:55}, 
                       {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90}, 
                       {name:'name',index:'name', width:100}, 
                       {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"}, 
                       {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"}, 
                       {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"}, 
                       {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} 
                      ], 
                 rowNum:10, 
                 rowList:[10,20,30], 
                 pager: '#pager5', 
                 sortname: 'id', 
                 viewrecords: true, 
                 sortorder: "desc", 
                 caption:"Simple data manipulation", 
                 editurl:"" 
                }).navGrid("#pager5",
                        {edit:false,add:false,del:false}); 
                        jQuery("#a1").click( function(){ 
                            var id = jQuery("#list5").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'); 
                            if (id) { 
                                var ret = jQuery("#list5").jqGrid('getRowData',id); 
                                alert("id="+ret.id+" invdate="+ret.invdate+"..."); 
                                } else { alert("Please select row");} 
                            });
</script>
```

&

> Firebug shows my response like this..

[[5,"CLM","Colombo","Colombo","Western"],[6,"HMB","Hambanthota","Colombo 07","Southern"]]

Then friends where is my error.? ? ?data not shown in my grid

Comment: Is it need jsonReader option.?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs some modifications; I am assuming the client is POSTing something in this example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectHarbour", method = POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> createEntity(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Specialist specialist) {
    specialistBo.save(specialist);
    final int id = specialist.getId();
    URI uri = new UriTemplate("{requestUrl}/{username}").expand(request.getRequestURL().toString(), id);
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.put("Location", singletonList(uri.toASCIIString()));
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

If you want to GET something it should be similar to this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public
@ResponseBody
Page<Specialist> listEntities(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int page,
                              @RequestParam(value = "max", required = false, defaultValue = "5") int max,
                              @RequestParam(value = "sidx", required = false, defaultValue = "grid_name") String sidx,
                              @RequestParam(value = "sord", required = false, defaultValue = "desc") String sord,
                              @RequestParam(value = "filters", required = false, defaultValue = "") String filters) {
    return specialistBo.getSpecialist(page, max, stringStringMap.get(sidx), sord, filters);
}
```

---

```
   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<Specialist> getSpecialist(int page, int max, String sidx, String sord, String filters) {
        int count = ((Long) getSession().createQuery("select count(*) from Specialist").iterate().next()).intValue();
        final int start = max * page - max;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Specialist> list =
                getSession().createCriteria(Specialist.class)
                        .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("name like '%%' order by %s %s limit %s,%s")).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
        return new Page<Specialist>(list, page, max, count);
    }
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({Specialist.class, Aptitude.class})
    public class Page<T> {
        private List<T> rows;
        private int page;
        private int max;
        private int total;
```

You will need to create getters and setters for Page. Hope this helps a bit